# Is the :last-child selector bad for performance?

Tags: performance, css, css-selectors

I use `:last-child` selector plenty of times, mostly when using `border-bottom` in a list where I use `border: none;` for the last child, or when using margins. So my question is, is the `:last-child` selector bad from a performance point of view?

Also I've heard that it was removed from the CSS2 specification because using `:first-child` is easy for the browser to detect, but for detecting `:last-child` it needs to loop back.

Comment: If `:last-child` is only needed for removing bottom border from the last child of the list, you could add top-border and remove it from `first:child`. Of course, it might not meet your requirements.

Comment: have you already read this? http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors

Comment: @t.niese: CSS4 will probably introduce parent selector, :last-child is also in specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/ (but of course implementations might have performance issues as the article shows)

Comment: @buli well it's more about the part _Why IE took so long to get :last-child support_

Comment: @t.niese I was talking in general :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien me too. there is also an information about: `Firefox treats the last element loaded as the last element until it gets a new one.` `In Safari, Chrome and Opera [...] These browsers don't treat any element as the last element until it closes the parent element.` just thought this observation could be from interest, why there could have been concerns about bad performance. anyway i don't think it is a real problem because if you look at the dynamics pages with where js is creating and removing element over and over again. i would not expect that `:last-child` would be _the_ problem.

Comment: @t.niese That was a nice fact, did you got any link for an article which explains this?

Comment: @Mr.Alien this is from the link of my first comment (in section `Why IE took so long to get :last-child support` the problem is explained.) in the following section are the parts i quoted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it was deferred from CSS2 for performance concerns, but reintroduced in Selectors 3, I suspect that it's because performance is no longer an issue as it previously was.

Remember that `:last-child` is the **definitive** and **only** way to select the last child of a parent (besides `:nth-last-child(1)`, obviously). If browser implementers no longer have performance concerns, neither should we as authors.

The only compelling reason I can think of for overriding a border style with `:first-child` as opposed to `:last-child` is to allow compatibility with IE7 and IE8. If that boosts performance, let that be a side effect. If you don't *need* IE7 and IE8 support, then you shouldn't feel compelled to use `:first-child` over `:last-child`. Even if browser performance is absolutely critical, you should be addressing it the proper way by testing and benchmarking, not by premature optimization.

Comment: If you have control over the rendering of the page on the server, then `last-child` isn't the only way to select the last child element of another element. You could add a class and select it using that.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the core CSS selectors perform well enough that most of us should not be worried about using them. Yes, some of them do perform worse than others, but even the worst performing ones are unlikely to be the main bottleneck in your site.

Unless you've already optimised everything else to perfection, I would advise not worrying about this. Use a profiling tool like YSlow to find the *real* performance issues on your site and fix those.

In any case, even if there is a noticable performance implication for a given CSS selector (or any other browser feature), I would say that it's the browser makers' responsibility to fix it, not yours to work around it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it's still the simplest, low-performance way to get your last child.
by that I mean, all others way to get the last child will be worse for performance, because it won't have any work done by the W3C community before.

Comment: no, but as it is a feature in the specification, and because the W3C made it a fully documented selector, we can only assume they did work on it.

Comment: Specification and implementation are two different things. It doesn't matter whether the selector is officially part of the CSS specification or not. Just claiming that there are no issues because a group of people thought about what it *should* do is not a very strong argument.

Comment: the group of people in question is the one who pretty much set all the rules on internet programmation and some of them are the ones designing the browsers. I believe that if they made the choice to implement last-child as it is, there must be a reason as it's also their job to read this CSS afterward, in their browsers

Comment: @Felix Kling: They're closely related anyway - specifications do drop or defer features if there are too few interoperable implementations, which is allegedly what happened here with `:last-child`. That said, your last statement still holds true - especially when there are no references to back up such claims.