# Why does CSS3 have both a :first-child and :nth-child() pseudo-class selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Why does CSS3 have both a `:first-child` and `:nth-child()` pseudo-class selector?

I'm curious what the point is of `:first-child`, shouldn't `:nth-child(1)` select the exact same thing?

It seems weird to me to have two pseudo-class selectors to do the same thing and the only reason I can see is that `:first-child` is one character less to type but that comes at the expense of having one more pseudo-class selector to remember.

Comment: it seems weird now, but older IE versions don't support `nth-child`.

Comment: They were introduced at different times, `:first-child` [in CSS 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#first-child), `:nth-child` [in CSS 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).

Comment: Retrocompatibility is VERY important when your technology is ubiquitous

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's simply due to evolution of the CSS standard.

- `first-child` is a [CSS Level 2 selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-elements)
- `nth-child` is a [CSS Level 3 selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo)

CSS2 doesn't suddenly become obsolete just because CSS3 exists. From the CSS3 spec:

> This document describes the selectors that already exist in CSS1 and CSS2, and further introduces new selectors for CSS3 and other languages that may need them.

Comment: It would seem to me that logically, it wouldn't make sense to have a :last-child selector without also having a :first-child selector.  :nth-child() can't select a last child element in a dynamic setting.  Only if you know the last child is the 5th element for example can you make that work with nth-child.  Also, CSS is made to be rather "verbose"  Beyond all of the above reasons, it is a lot easier to read :first-child and :last-child than :nth-child(1) or :nth-child(5)

Comment: @Michael: ":nth-child() can't select a last child element in a dynamic setting." That's why :nth-last-child() was introduced as a complement to :nth-child().

Comment: The *real* reason why :last-child didn't exist until CSS3 was because it was originally proposed for CSS2, then deferred due to complications not really well-known. [Poor performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144036/is-the-last-child-selector-bad-for-performance/16144769#16144769) Poor implementation? Not sure, but whatever it was, the fact that it didn't make it to CSS2 wasn't entirely an accident.

Answer (score 5):

If I'm not mistaken, the `:first-child` was added in CSS2 whereas `:nth-child()` was added in CSS3 - likely "building upon" the former mentioned psuedo-classes.

On a side note, `:first-child` will work in IE7 whereas `:nth-child(1)` will not so they don't always select the exact same thing.

**Sources**

http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/css3-pseudo-classes/
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#first-child

Comment: Not to mention :last-child being introduced.  You could make an argument on keeping first-child just because last-child became a thing, despite all the other stuff above.

Comment: @Michael `:nth-last-child()` was also added in CSS3 so `:last-child` isn't mandatory either to select last elements (though I'm glad it exists. Way easier to use and read for most people)

Answer (score 1):

[`:first-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child) was introduced in [CSS Selectors level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) while [`:nth-child()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) belongs to [Selectors level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

[Not the all web browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) (including IE8 and below) support the new CSS pseudo classes and also the old pseudo classes are widely used and [they're also part of Level 3 selectors as well](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#abstract).

Answer (score 1):

Besides all the correct answers about different implementation versions of both selectors, I would assume this is some kind of convention following the principle of least surprise:

There is a `:last-child` selector which is some kind of special thing (that can't be *replaced* with any `:nth-child` selector call (okay, besides some dirty hacks)), so one would always expect there is also a `:first-child`.

I personally would be very confused if I see any `last` function/selector without an equivalent `first`.

The other way round this might be different (as `first` is more useful in most cases, e.g. for text highlighting the first character of a chapter in a book etc.). So there is the `::first-letter` selector, but there is no `::last-letter` (yet?). But I wouldn't expect there is one, because no one really highlights the last letter of a text in practical. That's what happened with the `:first-child` selector too: It got introduced with CSS2, but that time there was no `:last-child` yet and got introducted with CSS3 together with the `:nth-child` selector.

Comment: ::first-letter even *pre-dates* :first-child. ::first-letter was already around in CSS1, whereas :first-child was introduced in CSS2.